# How can I get the MPEG-TS support for GStreamer?

Tags: plugins, gstreamer

Trying to play a MPEG-TS stream with `gst-play` in a 22.04 box, I get:

```
Missing decoder: MPEG-2 Transport Stream (video/mpegts, systemstream=(boolean)true, packetsize=(int)188)
```

while it works fine in another one (also with 22.04).

Where it works, I get:

```
$ gst-inspect-1.0 mpegtsdemux
Plugin Details:
  Name                     mpegtsdemux
  Description              MPEG TS demuxer
  Filename                 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmpegtsdemux.so
  Version                  1.20.3
  License                  LGPL
  Source module            gst-plugins-bad
  Source release date      2022-06-15
  Binary package           GStreamer Bad Plugins (Ubuntu)
  Origin URL               https://launchpad.net/distros/ubuntu/+source/gst-plugins-bad1.0

  tsdemux: MPEG transport stream demuxer
  tsparse: MPEG transport stream parser

  2 features:
  +-- 2 elements
```

while where it doesn't:

```
$ gst-inspect-1.0 mpegtsdemux
No such element or plugin 'mpegtsdemux'
```

But as far as I can see, the plugin should be available here too. The file is there

```
$ls -l /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmpegtsdemux.so
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 197488 Jun 29  2022 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gstreamer-1.0/libgstmpegtsdemux.so
```

and the "bad" plugins package in installed:

```
$ apt list gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
Listing... Done
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad/jammy-updates,now 1.20.3-0ubuntu1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad/jammy-updates 1.20.3-0ubuntu1 i386
```

What could be missing? How can I refresh the plugin database/registry/whatever? I tried `apt-get install --reinstall gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad` with no apparent effect.

Comment: It looks like the registry is cached in `~/.cache/gstreamer-1.0/registry.x86_64.bin`, removing it worked, but maybe there's a better way to refresh it...